# Prove or disprove that the set of continuous mappings $\phi\colon [0;1]\to [0;1]$ such that [...] forms a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, relations

The full question: Prove or disprove that the set of all continuous <s>relations</s> mappings $ \phi\colon [0;1]\to [0;1]$, for which $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi(1)=1$ and $x<y \implies \phi(x)< \phi(y)$ forms a group with respect to the operation of superposition/composition.

I was able to prove closure by noting that the intersection of their domains is simply the interval $[0;1]$ itself thus the composition will also be a <s>relation</s> mapping from $[0;1]$ to $[0;1]$.

At this point, I decided to prove associativity. I first considered this well-known proof: 
$$h\circ(g\circ f)(x)=h(g\circ f(x))= h(g(f(x))=h\circ g(f(x))=(h\circ g)\circ f(x)$$
However, this is a proof for *function* composition whereas the question is about  <s>relations</s>  mappings. So, since the question asked about <s>relations</s> mappings and not just functions, is this proof of associativity still valid? After all, it seems to me that all the continuous increasing <s>relations</s> mappings from $[0;1]$ to $[0;1]$ are indeed functions. (I'm guessing this statement would require it's own proof, which i'm trying to draft as well.)

Stuck on associativity, I decided to see if the other group axioms would be easier to work with. I verified than an identity function $i(x)=x$ exists, satisfying the conditions of the problem. Then I had more trouble with proving that the inverses will also be continious and within the interval so I'm inclined to conclude that the set is not a group. Any hints on how to proceed with this proof or disproof?

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous relation"?  What does $\phi(x)$ mean if $\phi$ is a relation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. (It seems there is some subtext?)
Well, a relation is any set of ordered pairs. A continuous relation is a relation which is defined for all points in a given interval.

Comment: OK, a relation is a set of ordered pairs.  What does $\phi(0)=0$ mean, then, if $\phi$ is a set of ordered pairs?  (The subtext is that "continuous relation" is not a standard term at all, nor is it standard to use notation like $\phi(x)$ when talking about relations.)

Comment: And, what does it mean for a relation to be "defined" for a point?  Maybe $\phi$ is defined for $x$ if there exists $y$ such that $(x,y)\in\phi$?

Comment: The problem was translated from a Russian text so it's possible some details were missed. However it should be more or less clear what is being asked. This is how I understand it: Let G be the set of relations $ \phi_n$ from $[0;1]$ to $[0;1]$ satisfying the conditions described in the question. The question is whether or not G and the operation of composition forms a group. Does this help clarify?

Comment: No, it doesn't clarify anything.  What I am asking is what the conditions described in the question even mean.

Comment: They're giving restrictions on what *type* of relations to consider.  The first condition insists that the ordered pairs (0,0) and (1,1) $\in \phi_n$. The second condition is that all $\phi_n$ are increasing.

Comment: Perhaps "continuous relation" here is "continuous function", as "continuous" isn't something that one could usually attach to a relation (unless the relation is in fact a function). This is odd since functziya is function in russian, I believe...Why would the OP use relation instead I don't know.

Comment: @DonAntonio I looked up the Russian version. It doesn't use the word Функция (Function) but the word Отоброжений (relations). I doubt the question is about equivalence relations because  it was given in an introductory algebra class after having had studied only sets,  relations, functions and basic content on algebraic systems (groups, rings and fields).

Comment: @DonAntonio please see if the current edit helps.

Comment: @EricWofsey please see if the current edit helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
So first of all the associativity follows from the general fact about functions: if we have

$$\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> B @>{g}>> C @>{h}>> D
\end{CD} $$

then $h\circ(g\circ f)=(h\circ g)\circ f$ regardless of what those functions are. This can be checked by evaluating each side at $x\in A$ as you've done yourself.

Now the set of all bijections (not necessarily continuous) from a set to itself is a group together with $\circ$ as a group multiplication. Denote this group by $\mathcal{F}(X)$.

So now it is enough to show that the set you are looking at is a subgroup of $\mathcal{F}(X)$.

(1) So first of all if $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is such that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f$ is continuous and monotonic then $f$ is a bijection. This follows from the intermediate value theorem.

Denote by $\mathcal{M}([0,1])$ the set of all those functions.

(2) The set $\mathcal{M}([0,1])$ is closed under $\circ$. This you claim you've shown. The proof is quite simple though. If $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$ and thus so is $g(f(x))<g(f(y))$. Meaning $g\circ f\in\mathcal{M}([0,1])$ if both $f,g\in\mathcal{M}([0,1])$.

(3) If $f\in \mathcal{M}([0,1])$ then $f^{-1}\in\mathcal{M}([0,1])$. So obviously $f^{-1}(0)=0$ and $f^{-1}(1)=1$. Now we will show that $f^{-1}$ is monotonic. Indeed, assume that $x<y$. Then $x=f(a)$ and $y=f(b)$ since $f$ is bijective. But since $f$ is monotonic then case when $a=b$ or $a>b$ are impossible. It follows that $a<b$ and thus $f^{-1}(x)<f^{-1}(y)$.

Finally $f^{-1}$ is continuous simply because $[0,1]$ is compact and so $f$ is closed.